# Error odbc connect with symfony 7 parsing mdb file

Tags: docker, symfony, mdbtools

I want to parse an mdb file using odbc_connect. I created a docker for this and I get this error.

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'MDBTools' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect
```

I installed mdbtools but it doesn't work.

I put the mdb file in the /public directory.

Here is my dockerfile.

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# COMMON ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# make sure apt is up to date
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing \
    && apt-get install -y \
        mdbtools \
        curl  \
        build-essential \
        libssl-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libldap2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        vim \
        debconf \
        subversion \
        git \
        apt-transport-https \
        apt-utils \
        locales \
        acl \
        mailutils \
        wget \
        zip \
        unzip \
        gnupg \
        gnupg1 \
        gnupg2 \
        wkhtmltopdf \
        xvfb \
    && apt-get clean
# end COMMON -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RUN apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y --force-yes

RUN docker-php-source extract
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc \
    && cd /usr/src/php/ext/odbc \
    && phpize \
    && sed -ri 's@^ *test +"\$PHP_.*" *= *"no" *&& *PHP_.*=yes *$@#&@g' configure \
    && ./configure --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install odbc

# LOCALE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RUN sed -i -e 's/# fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen
ENV LANG fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE fr_FR:fr
ENV LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8
# end LOCALE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# PDOSQL, IMAGICK, SOAP
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
      pdo \
      pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install soap \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install sockets

# end PDOSQL, IMAGICK, SOAP

# Imagick
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagickwand-6.q16-dev --no-install-recommends \
 && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/MagickWand-config /usr/bin \
 && pecl install imagick \
 && echo "extension=imagick.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini
# end Imagick

COPY php-fpm-pool.conf /etc/php/8.2/pool.d/www.conf

# PHP INI --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARG PHP_INI=php.ini
COPY $PHP_INI /usr/local/etc/php/
# end PHP INI ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# PHP ODBC INST --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARG ODBCINST_INI=odbcinst.ini
COPY $ODBCINST_INI /usr/local/etc/
# end PHP ODBC INST ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# PHP ODBC --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARG ODBC_INI=odbc.ini
COPY $ODBC_INI /usr/local/etc/
# end PHP ODBC ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Install composer -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN groupadd dev -g 1001
RUN useradd dev -g dev -d /home/dev -m
# end Install composer -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# NODE JS, YARN et PYTHON ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RUN mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nodejs=16.20.2-1nodesource1  -y
RUN apt-get install npm -y

RUN apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev -y \
 && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr \
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc

#RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
#RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
# node js >= 16
RUN npm install -g corepack
RUN corepack enable
# node js < 16
#RUN npm i -g corepack

RUN yarn init -2
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install python3 -y
# npm rebuild node-sass a lancer dans le bash si besoin après update (docker exec -it sf4_php bash)
# end NODE JS, YARN et PYTHON ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

WORKDIR /home/www


EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Mdbtools is installed in docker.

[image]

Do you have any idea where this could come from?

Thank you for your help